# Are these upper ball joints universal (driver/passenger side) or is it a mistake?

Tags: ford, suspension

I have this 1994 Ford Crown Victoria (police interceptor). I wanted to replace **upper** ball joints but there's this thing I can't understand.

On ebay and other part dealers websites, some uppper ball joints (for example, [acdelco](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ACDELCO-45D0072-Ball-Joint-Upper-/170689967963?pt=Motors_Car_Truck_Parts_Accessories&fits=Year:1994%7CMake%3aFord%7CModel%3aCrown%20Victoria%7CSubmodel%3aPolice%20Interceptor&vxp=mtr&hash=item27bdea375b#ht_1150wt_1270)) are marked as **driver side** or **passenger side** and others (like [moog](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Moog-K8600-Upper-Ball-Joint-/400220660922?pt=Motors_Car_Truck_Parts_Accessories&fits=Year%3A1994%7CMake%3AFord%7CModel%3ACrown+Victoria%7CSubmodel%3APolice+Interceptor&vxp=mtr&hash=item5d2f02a4ba#ht_1247wt_931) or [motorcraft](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MOTORCRAFT-MCS-104156-Ball-Joint-Upper-/170640005076?pt=Motors_Car_Truck_Parts_Accessories&fits=Year%3A1994%7CMake%3AFord%7CModel%3ACrown+Victoria%7CSubmodel%3APolice+Interceptor&vxp=mtr&hash=item27baefd7d4#ht_1134wt_931)) are not. So is it safe to assume they can be installed on both sides?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a ball joint that couldn't be used on either side.

Ford is notorious for specifying different part numbers for each side, or, appending an L or an R to the part number.

Comment: Hey, Jaime. I have a pair of new motorpro upper ball joints which sadly don't fit the car, but anyway, they are not the same -  I've just checked (one of them even have an extruded L). Their numbers are different too (*5 and *6, or something like that). And all the Motorcraft joints I've seen have the same number and no side specification. I wouldn't ask all this, but I'll have to make an international order, and I don't wanna end sending it back.

Comment: I've just had a chat with a live support at one of the parts dealers. He told that ball joints which don't have the side specified can be used on either side. So it kinda answers the question. Thank you, Jaime.